# how and where do I initialize an global NSMutableArray in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, initialization, xcode5, xcode5.0.1

I am trying to initialize a global NSMutableArray that I can add integers to later. I just need to know how and where I should initialize my array so that it can be accessed and changed by any function that I use later in my program. Also I am using Xcode 5 and know that the array needs to be 180 in length.

Answer (score 4):

In your AppDelegate.h file -

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *sharedArray;
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize sharedArray;
```

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions -

```
sharedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Now,

make create shared object of AppDelegate like-

```
mainDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

and access sharedArray where you want to access using-

```
mainDelegate.sharedArray
```

Comment: Where do I put the mainDelegate = . . .? Does it also go in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: mainDelegate is an object of your AppDelegate. In yourViewController.h file initialise AppDelegate *mainDelegate; and in yourViewController.m file's viewDidLoad - mainDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; In this way you can get copy of AppDelegate with sharedArray.Try this.

Comment: I get the error "No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'delegate'

Answer (score 4):

You could create a singleton class and define a property for your array on that class.

for example:

```
// .h file
@interface SingletonClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *yourArray; 
+(SingletonClass*) sharedInstance;
@end

// .m file

@implementation SingletonClass

+(SingletonClass*) sharedInstance{
    static SingletonClass* _shared = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _shared = [[self alloc] init];
        _shared.yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     });
     return _shared;
  }

@end
```

Comment: That's the way to do it. It is quite a bad practice to add all kinds of stuff to the app delegate as was suggested. I think you may have to assign "_shared.yourArray" instead.

Comment: can I use this in a non ARC?

Answer (score 3):

Creating a **Singleton** class is the better option for you. In this singleton class, you can initialize the array. Later, you can access this array from any class by using this singleton class. A great benefit is you dont need to initialize the class object everytime. You can access the array using a **sharedObject**.

Below is a tutorial for Singletons in objective C

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: I followed the tutorial and initialized my array. I then tried to replace an object in the array using: `[idArray replaceObjectAtIndex:nextIndex withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"red"]];` Next I tried to print my array in the console using nslog but it returns null; so I am still initializing the array wrong or am I using the replaceObjectAtIndex wrong?

Comment: if your array returns null, then you may not be initialized the array

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise your array in app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, as this is called pretty much immediately after your app is launched:

```
// In a global header somewhere
static NSMutableArray *GlobalArray = nil;

// In MyAppDelegate.m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    GlobalArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:180];
    ...
}
```

**Alternatively**, you could use **lazy instantiation**:

```
// In a global header somewhere
NSMutableArray * MyGlobalArray (void);

// In an implementation file somewhere
NSMutableArray * MyGlobalArray (void)
{
    static NSMutableArray *array = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:180];
    });
    return array;
 }
```

You can then access the global instance of the array using `MyGlobalArray()`.

However, this is ***not* considered good design practice in object-oriented programming**. Think about what your array is for, and possibly store it in a singleton object that manages related functionality, rather than storing it globally.