# how to implement uisearchcontroller for complete app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I know how to implement `UISearchController` for a table view. But can anyone help me in implementing search bar for complete app.

In my app i have 3 view controllers
a)students VC
b)teachers VC
c)parents VC

and I have a search `button`. Here i want to implement complete in app search functionality. If we type in a name it should appear in a table view either it is in students/parents/teachers. I am not getting any idea how to start this. Please give some KT.

Comment: you need an global array that contain all the data about students, teachers and parents then you can get the result as per your expectation.

Comment: hi Nitin.. I have 3 different json/dictionary for parents/students/teachers.. how can i make one global array with 3 json files?

Comment: Check this create singlaton global class or NSObject, you can also create mutablearray in appdelegate and use it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995395/how-and-where-do-i-initialize-an-global-nsmutablearray-in-xcode-5

Comment: i just added an answer about global array hope you got the solution about.

Answer (score 0):

I just try to create singleton class that store value and use as a global. So first you need to create a Singleton-class using following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobalData : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *ClassArray;
}
+(GlobalData *) getInstance;
-(void)saveClassARray:(NSArray *)array;
-(NSMutableArray *)getGlobalArray;

@end
```

**It's .M Class**

```
#import "GlobalData.h"
@implementation GlobalData
static GlobalData *instanceGlobalData;

+(GlobalData *) getInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
       instanceGlobalData = [[GlobalData alloc] init];
        instanceGlobalData->ClassArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];;
    });

    return instanceGlobalData;
}

-(void)saveClassARray:(NSArray *)array
{
    [ClassArray addObjectsFromArray:array];

}
-(NSMutableArray *)getGlobalArray
{
    return ClassArray;
}

@end
```

Now you need to store your Students, Teachers and Parents data by following code.

First you need to import `#import "GlobalData.h"` in your ViewController and create define variable that like following:

```
#import "GlobalData.h"
#define USERDATASINGLETON (GlobalData *)[GlobalData getInstance]
```

And in Web services Call back Success you need to store your data in globle array using following code:

```
NSArray *array =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Nitin",@"Nit", nil];
[USERDATASINGLETON saveClassARray:array];
```

Above array is just for your referance do same things for all your 3 `ViewController` and store the result using `saveClassARray`. now finally you need to get full array by following code:

```
NSMutableArray *FinalGlobalArray = [USERDATASINGLETON getGlobalArray];
NSLog(@"==%@",FinalGlobalArray);
```

That will be NSlog allof the data that have you stored. but make sure use some check that **once you add teacher,student,parents data and if `saveClassARray` calling again that old data wont be overtire that will be create duplicate entry so take care about**.

Now you have finalArray you can do your search code that you have did for individual.

Hope that help